# How to install Sourcepole zonal statistics

Tags: qgis, plugins

I am trying to install the zonal statistics tool created/supplied by sourcepole from http://www.sourcepole.com/2010/12/16/zonal-statistics-plugin-for-qgis.

The instructions area as follows:

****To install: unpack zonal_statistics.tgz under /src/plugins, insert zonal_statistics as new subdirectory in /src/plugins/CMakeLists.txt and recompile.****

I have downloaded and unzipped the file, but I am now not sure how to add it to the QGIS software.  I am using a Mac OS, and QGIS version 1.7.4.

I can't find the folder /src/plugins which the instructions speak of.... and in general am very confused by the instructions (more due to my semi-computer illiteracy than the instructions themselves).

Any help I would greatly appreciate.

Regards

Becky

Comment: Which function of Zonal Statistics plugin do you need? Maybe there is another solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Zonal statistics** comes readily installed in the current developer version of QGIS.

Maybe it will be included in the 1.8 release which should come out quite soon.

If you have to use 1.7.4, maybe try **[ZonalStats](http://gis-lab.info/qa/zonalstats-qgis-eng.html)** plugin instead.

As "semi-computer illiterate" (as you stated), chances to succeed with compiling QGIS on Mac OS are low.

Comment: I have tried this zonal statistics tool - but it only calculates the area.  The dialogue box provides no other statistics options

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but looking into the files and seeing the text "recompile" I am sure that this archive contains source-code (C or C++ ?) , which you need to compile, it is not usable together with a already compiled version of gqis (= a version for normal endusers, like "you and me").

compile = using a software tool from source-code into an exectuable program. this can be very tricky for the more mortal version of mankind. you will need an computer-expert for this task